# Teradata ignore error for multiple queries in same window

Tags: teradata

I'm running multiple drop statements directly using Teradata SQL Assistant in the same query window.

For example:

```
DROP TABLE publish.a;
DROP TABLE publish.b;
DROP TABLE publish.c;
DROP TABLE publish.d;
```

The problem is that some of the tables may not be present due to which the code will stop executing and will throw an error "Drop table failed [3807]"

I've tried using the .goto label but I am unable to find a way to simply "continue with the next statement"

I even tried

```
.set maxerror 100;
.set retry on;
.set errorlevel 3807 severity 0;
```

with no luck.

Comment: Uncheck *Tools > Options > Query > "Stop query execution if an SQL error occurs"*

Comment: Thanks a lot! that works
should have looked for that (Face-palm)